# Is there a way to open a file in VS Code from the integrated terminal/codespace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The integrated terminal in VS code means that you can run builds, scripts and other commands and see the results as is. Sometimes though they produce output files that you'd like to view in an editor, like a logfile or exception trace.

Is there a way of running a built-in command in the terminal to say 'please open this file in vscode', specifically in a codespace? On macOS, you might use 'open' or 'start' on Windows, but this only works if your codespace is hosted on the same machine that you're browsing to.

It would be great if there was a command that could be run that would open up the corresponding file in vscode, such that you could set the `VIEW` or `EDITOR` environment variables and have such operations edit in the file itself. Then (for example) running `git` in the integrated terminal would open a new vscode editor for writing the git message, instead of the default vi/emacs/notepad/edit.com/pico/nano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. Use the command:

```
code filename
```

Or, if you are running an early release (or GitHub codespaces):

```
code-insiders filename
```